# Easiest way to refactor var to explicit type in C# with VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In `Visual Studio Code` (not `Visual Studio`) I want to automatically refactor `var` types to `explicit` types when writing code in `C#`.

Is there an extension/feature in `visual-studio-code` that allows this?

Example - automatically convert this:

```
var x = 10;
```

to

```
int x = 10;
```

This is the same functionality in `Visual Studio`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-var-to-explicit-type?view=vs-2019

Comment: Do you want to change the implicit types to explicit ones in case of an existing codebase?

Comment: Yes, preferably being able to do it line-by-line instead of all at once.

Answer (score 1):

The [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) by Microsoft offers this functionality.